# Is there a good way to log my android app events?

Tags: android, logging

Is there a good way or library to log each method in my android app using something like interceptors or anything else .. but without writing more code to add the below line

```
Log.d("KEY", "Method name(params)");
```

Answer (score 0):

use [logger](https://github.com/orhanobut/logger), is best lib for log in android

[image]

Comment: I used this library before, but my question is how to use it without writing more code in my android app .. I need something like intercepting the code .. not to adding logs in each method .. thanks for ur reply

Comment: @ahmedewess you have to write at least 1 line each event/medhod you want to be logged. There is no alternative way to do it. There is no Library or AI exists to guess what you want to do it.